# Why can't I convert a column from one enum to another?

Tags: postgresql, enums, alter-column

Given this setup

```sql
create type myenum_one as enum('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

create table mytable (
  myvalue myenum_one
);

alter table mytable
add constraint mycheckconstraint check (myvalue != 'bar');

insert into mytable values ('foo');

create type myenum_two as enum('foo', 'bar');
```

It then fails on when trying to alter the column type

```sql
alter table mytable
alter column myvalue type myenum_two using myvalue::text::myenum_two;
```

With error

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: enum_two <> enum_one
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the check constraint before altering the column type, and the recreate it after (if it's still relevant), like so

```sql
alter table mytable
drop constraint mycheckconstraint;

alter table mytable
alter column myvalue type myenum_two using myvalue::text::myenum_two;

alter table mytable
add constraint mycheckconstraint check (myvalue != 'bar');
```